# How to determine if a value is a valid datetime format or not

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I tried parse string values like `2019-04-30T06:46:31.811:00` to a DateTime with `DateTime.ParseExact()`. No one pattern that I used doesn't fit.

I came to a conclusion that `:00` in the end of datetime string this is not valid and expected pattern, that will be represent time zone should be like `+05` or `+05:00`

Some variant of patterns that I used:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffz"
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff':'z"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff':'zz"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff':'Z"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff':'K"
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff':'ss"
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff:zz"
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff:zz"
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff:zz"
"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff:zz"
```

Comment: @Viacheslav Yes, `:00` isn't valid as it should be `+00` for example. You can already imagine that if it's invalid, you should do some "maintenance" in your string values otherwise they won't be parsed at all. Have you already tried doing something about it?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Thank you for your comment. No, this is not needed. I will show this dates as raw value.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you can *control* the format you use, or whether you're just having to parse existing data? If it's the latter, do *all* the values end in ":00" or are there other offsets there? (I assume it really is meant to be a UTC offset?)

Comment: Thank for your all comments. My goal was determine is this string valid for datetime or not. That's it. I don't need to fix it. Answer is: "This sting is not valid for datetime".

Comment: It's not that it's "not valid for datetime" - a format string of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff':00'` would work, for example. But that *wouldn't* work for a value of 2019-04-30T06:46:31.811:01.

Comment: Side note: +05 wouldn't represent a time zone, it would represent a UTC offset *in* a particular (but unknown) time zone at that point in time.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank for comment. Yes, hardcode for ```':00'``` works, but, how you say, this is not a suitable solution, if end of string has been changed.

Comment: Which is why I asked whether all the values end in :00 or not. (That's entirely plausible.) And even if it *does* vary, there are other alternatives (such as Noda Time, which can convert back to DateTime if you really want). This is why the more information you can provide, the more useful help you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

I use this format (2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z) And Its Work , You Can Convert this string To this format and Try this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-09-30T23:00:00.0000000Z",
                                       "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffff'Z'",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |
                                       DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
        Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get more clarity from the OP, but I *expect* that they can't choose the format they use.